# 2D Godot raycastin is unituitive to use & 2D Global coordinates and rotation

Tags: godot

Hey so i am working on a interactive mini game in my work. New to godot!
Item.rotate(rand_range(-1.22173,1.22173)) just shooting missiles apromaxily 70 degrees at random. Its doing more like 140 degrees and i don't know why when i rotate.

```
        Item = ammo.instance()
    Item.position = Vector2(960,0)
    Item.rotate(rand_range(-1.22173,1.22173))
    add_child(Item)
    bulletArray.append(Item)
    var rot = Item.rotation
    angle = rot + PI/2
    angleArray.append(angle)
```

then when i shoot it with bullet array loop:

```
x.position += Vector2(1, 0).rotated(angleArray[index]) * speed * delta
```

its like 1-3 degreees off sometimes you can slightly notice it so its weird.

I wanted raycasting to just use some visual elements there maybe add collider later dont know. I tried

```
var randomvec = Vector2(rand_range(-400, 1120),1080)
```

with local coordinates when y is = 0 window size is 1080 y. It jus shoots so much wider than it should. And theres no documentation i can find. when i used something more like ((-30,30),1080)*MAX (max was = 1050) i was getting better results.

Is there any reliable way to use global coordinates on 2D games. Mostly for everything.

Thanks ! Just trying something new to this engine.

Its good enough but its not perfect angle how to fix that ?

I tried those codes shooting works and angle is 98% perfect. Raycasting was really hard to get on right area on random. Tried looking some documentation but cant figure it out.

Easy way to just use global coordsinates for almost everything ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay im an idiot im working 12 hours a daý..... i just need to `Item.rotate(rand_range(-1.22173,1.22173))` / 2 Sorry about that im really overworking..... of course its 140 degrees.... but raycasting question and angle couple degrees off still stands. It was still better gameplay when it was little wider so i try 90 pii/2. lol haha. Need to have a break.

Answer (score 0):

As you must have figured out `1.22173` radians is `70º`. Which means the range from `-1.22173` to `1.22173` is a range from `-70º` to `70º` which is a total of `140º`.

---

I will also remind you that you can use the `to_local` and `to_global` methods to convert from and to global coordinates.

Furthermore in 2D you can use `global_rotation`.

And if you want to transform a direction, you can use `node2d.global_transform.basis_xform(direction)` (or use `basis_xform_inv` for the inverse).

---

> its like 1-3 degreees off sometimes you can slightly notice it so its weird.

I'm guessing this is floating point error. Work with the rotated direction (a unit vector), instead of storing an angle and rotating again. Or use the transform of the `Node2D` as mentioned above.